# Fade in jquery div show

Tags: javascript, jquery, delay, fadein, fadeout

I am trying to get the below script to fade in and fade out with a delay in between. It shows the div correctly and fades out as it should, but it doesn't fade in?

```
<?php
if(isset($_GET['updated'])) { ?>
<div id='updated'><p>The product was successfully added to your Shopping Cart</p></div>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
$('#updated').fadeIn(800).delay(3000).fadeOut(800)
</script>
<?php } ?>
```

Many thanks!

Answer (score 7):

```
$('#updated').hide().fadeIn(800).delay(3000).fadeOut(800);
```

You could also set it in the css:

```
#updated{
  display: none;
}
```

The problem is - it's already visible (by default).

Answer (score 7):

its because its already showing

```
<div id='updated' style="display:none">
```

fixes it

Answer (score 6):

You have to **hide** `div` before `fadeIn()`, you can use `hide()` method to hide the `div`.

```
<?php
if(isset($_GET['updated'])) { ?>
<div id='updated'><p>The product was successfully added to your Shopping Cart</p></div>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">

$('#updated').hide().fadeIn(800).delay(3000).fadeOut(800)
</script>
<?php } ?>
```